# How could block encryption in counter mode be secure from viewpoint of entropy?

Tags: block-cipher, entropy

A good block cipher e.g. AES running in counter mode is commonly considered to be secure. Assuming a perfectly random key, one could in this case from $128$ bits generate up to $2^{128}·128$ bits for stream encryption.

However, these bits could evidently have only $1/(2^{128})$ bit of entropy each on the average. Isn't it a paradox that such an encryption could nonetheless be secure?

Answer (score 4):

Summary: an entropy argument shows that block encryption in counter mode can't be *perfectly* secure.

The remark that any block cipher in CTR mode generates a keystream with very low entropy per bit of keystream is correct. That hints CTR mode is not secure against an hypothetical *unbounded* adversary. In fact that holds as soon as more bits of keystream are used than there are in the key (or sooner): that unbounded adversary could enumerate all the possible keys, and rule out some keystreams as impossible.

This does not contradict that AES128 is *practically* safe in most but not all situations, against a real *bounded* adversary.

As an example of why I write "most but not all situations", consider the feasible case where an [exbibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exbibyte) of data (a fraction of a day's worth of global internet traffic) is enciphered with AES-128 in CTR mode; that's $2^{56}$ blocks, and odds that two ciphertext blocks are exactly identical are a low but sizable $2^{-17}$; should that occur, an hypothetical adversary able to detect and locate that equality (which is much *more* difficult than the encryption itself, but might still be feasible) would have learnt one tiny bit of information about the corresponding plaintext blocks: they can't be exactly identical; and thus, assuming an all-zero plaintext was characteristic of non-activitly, the adversary would have learnt that there has been activity in at least one of the two spots where the equality is detected.

Comment: But do you consider my figure of entropy correct? If so, what is the magnitude of entropy that a key stream bit would need to have in practice for a more or less secure stream encryption?

Comment: @Mok-Kong Shen: Yes, your figure of $1/{2^{128}}$ bit of entropy per bit of key stream, after $2^{128}$ 128-bit blocks, with a 128-bit key-entropy, seems fully correct to me. But I can't answer the rest, and rather would say that "bit of entropy per bit of key stream" is not a useful indication of practical security.

Comment: I surmise that it seems anyway difficult to characterize a nice goal of design for stream encryptions, noting on the other hand that the perfect security of OTP is based on the concept of entropy.

Comment: @Mok-KongShen: when considering "perfect security" against an unbounded adversary, rather than "more or less secure" against a practical adversary, then "bit of entropy per bit of key stream" indeed matters: it must be at least 1.

Comment: Ok, but then how much security measures does one need in order to protect against a "practical" adversary? That's a rather fuzzy and hard to determine matter, isn't it?

Comment: @fgrieu Your calculation of $2^{65}$ blocks does only work when the plaintext blocks are approximately equi-distributed, not in the assumed case that most plaintext blocks were actually zero-blocks. (It's still the case that the attacker learns that the two blocks are not same, but it is even less clear what advantage this gives.)

Comment: @Mok-KongShen Against a practical adversary you need that all known attacks need more time than you'll give that adversary, with high probability. For example, an encryption scheme *is certainly practically secure* when an adversary with more computing power than the sun's energy output needs some thousands of years.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: yes inactivity reduces odds of collisions; still that's only by about 10% for 30% inactivity, and I have the right binary order of magnitude for 50% inactivity.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: But estimates based on computing power could be difficult/problematic due to uncertainty in predictions of future developments either in software (methods of computation) or in hardware, if the secrecy has to be maintained for quite a long time. I vaguely remember to have seen a paper where Rivest made such a claim for a RSA key size that is way smaller than what is currently considered to be appropriate.